# Vue3 composition API accordion menu, problem with showing data

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-composition-api

I try to show the data when it is true, but it doesn't work. I want to make an accordion menu (after clicking on a question, toggle an open property and show the answer if it's true)

Here is code:

```
<div class="accordion">
<h1 class="title">Frequently asked questions</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="card" v-for="(item, i) in dataBase" :key="i">
      <div class="card-header" @click="item.open = !item.open">
        <h1>{{item.q}}</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="card-body" v-show="item.open">
        {{item.d}}
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And data:

```
const dataBase = [{
  q: 'How much does it cost?',
  d: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
  open: false,
},
  {
    q: 'How it works?',
    d: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    open: false,
  }]
```

Can anyone help and explain why in the console log it changes to true => false and vice versa, but doesn't show the data when it's true? Im new in Vue.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working bro. i runned on my computer.

if you asked 'why true->false and false->'. true and false is boolean variable.

```
<div class="card-header" @click="item.open = !item.open">
```

and this line you did

```
item.open = !item.open // if item.open is true then here is false.
item.open = !item.open // if item.open is false then here is true.
```

what is this exclamation(!) in vue ?

```
!(false) // true
!(true) // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dataBase` property is not reactive, you should use `ref` to make it reactive :

```js
import {ref} from 'vue'
const dataBase = ref([{
  q: 'How much does it cost?',
  d: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
  open: false,
},
  {
    q: 'How it works?',
    d: 'Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.',
    open: false,
  }])
```